# Show Div On (Other) Div Click?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get one div to show once another div is clicked.

Here is the HTML I have right now:

```
<li><a href="#"><div class="parent7">Light Finish</div></a>
<li><a href="#"><div class="child1">Twin</div></a>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
  .parent7 {

        }
  .child1 {
        display: none;
    }
```

I'm not sure what my next step is. What code would I use to change             `.child1` display to block on click of        `.parent7`?

Comment: Click events require scripting. CSS doesn't react on click events beyond `:active`;

Comment: Here is an example of an onclick action: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick

Answer (score 3):

You could use javascript event `onclick`

```
<div onclick="myFunction()">Light Finish</div>
```

When the user click on the div, it call a function that you create like this :

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("TheIdOfTheDiv").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

just give a id to one of the div you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery to do what you need. Like this:

```
$(".parent7").on("click", function () {
    $(".child1").css("display", "block");
});
```

Below is how you would use the jQuery code. I am also putting information on how to link to the jQuery library in your html document.

Here is a very basic, but complete webpage page example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Page Title</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <style>
             .parent7 {

             }
             .child1 {
                 display: none;
             }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent7">Light Finish</div>
        <div class="child1">Twin</div>

        <script>
            $(".parent7").on("click", function () {
                $(".child1").css("display", "block");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can choose to get jQuery from a CDN (Content Delivery Network) just like I did in the above example, or you can download jQuery and link the file however you want. You can dowload jQuery [Here](https://jquery.com/download/).

Comment: @Gary-MylesMehlhoff I have updated the answer with information on how to use jQuery and where to put the code in an html document.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to do what you are asking in pure HTML/CSS, provided that you don't have to support IE8. It uses, however, a rather obscure technique. The key is to use the `target` psuedo-selector, which applies if the element is the target of a clicked link element.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <a href='#to-show'>Click to show other div.</a>
</div>
<div id='to-show'>Here I am.<div>
```

CSS:

```
#to-show{
  display: none;
}

#to-show:target{
  display: block;
}
```

Here's a link to the JSBin with this code: http://jsbin.com/dirugavoba/edit?html,css,js,output

Now, that being said, the best way to accomplish interactivity really is with JavaScript. Despite this proof of concept, JavaScript provides far more intuitive and versatile ways to provide this functionality. The only real reason to use the technique I'm showing here is if you want or have to cater to the small handful of users who still turn JavaScript off.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript when dealing with clickevents and manipulating the html/style.

Look at the "onclick" method which can be set on an html element.